# How to automatically enable ethernet tethering on Android 11?

Tags: tethering, android-11

Each time the router reboots, the ethernet tethering (introduced in Android 11) breaks, and I'm trying to make it recovers automatically.

Developer options have a setting for enabling USB tethering on USB cable plug.

Is there anything similar for ethernet tethering?

Comment: You could set your router not to reboot.

Comment: it's rebooted by power outage of entire house which happens on a regular basis

Comment: Can someone help to create a solution using a shell at startup? https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/247954/how-to-enable-ethernet-tethering-via-shell-android-12-for-a-start-up-script

Answer (score 2):

Ok, got it working with [Interact](http://llamalab.com/automate/doc/block/interact.html) block in [Automate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.llamalab.automate).
It has a nice inspector I used for capturing an ethernet tethering tap event.

[image: Automate]

Reproducing tap only works with the screen unlocked so I used [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) with [AutoInput](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autoinput) plugin to unlock the screen on the cable plug.